# Ito Integral Function

Tags: integration

Let $s→v(x)$ be a smooth deterministic function with $\sup_{0≤s≤t}|v′(s)| ≤C$. Prove directly from the definition of the Ito integral that $\int_0^t v(s)\ dB(s) =v(t)B(t)− \int_0^t v′(s)B(s)\ ds$

See below: [image]